# How well does OOB estimate the generalization error?

Tags: machine-learning, hypothesis-testing, confidence-interval

I frequently see people evaluate the models using the OOB, but well does OOB estimates the generalisation error? Is it an unbiased estimator for the generalisation error ? How large is the margin of error (I guess it largely depends on some factor like the sample size) ? Is there any paper related to this topic?

From what I know, at least the test set error is the unbiased estimator of generalisation error, but if OOB is a biased estimates, then there's a tendency that it won't estimate the test set error well...

Comment: [How would one formally prove that the OOB error in random forest is unbiased?](https://stats.stackexchange.com/questions/105811/how-would-one-formally-prove-that-the-oob-error-in-random-forest-is-unbiased)

Comment: Be careful in implying that a biased estimator is bad estimator. A biased estimator can be a perfectly reasonable estimator. For instance, the usual estimator of standard deviation, $S = \sqrt{\dfrac{1}{n-1}\sum_{i=1}^n\bigg(X_i-\bar X\bigg)^2}$, is biased.